# What does github actions uses under the hood?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I have been really curious to know-how GitHub actions works under the hood. Does it uses azure-pipelines or is it something custom built specifically for GitHub?

Usage is really simple, but if anyone can explain the underlying mechanics that would be really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub actions uses C# [runner](https://github.com/actions/runner). If you want to you can host it on your infrastructure ([self-hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#about-self-hosted-runners)).